# Why does Python not like double underscore in a python string do?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I've been reading about mangling and what double underscores do in Python, but does all that apply with a string field inside single quotes?

In code sample below,
`'C:\\Apps\\Quotes\\data\\GetQuoteslog__2020_08_11.txt'` fails
but
`'C:\\Apps\\Quotes\\data\\GetQuoteslog_2020_08_11.txt'` works.

```
def log_message(logFilename, logMessageText):
    #logFilename = "./data/GetQuotesStoreBlobs_log.txt"
    file1 = open(logFilename, "a")  # append mode
    file1.write(logMessageText + "\n")
    file1.close()


filename = 'C:\\Apps\\Quotes\\data\\GetQuoteslog__2020_08_11.txt'
print("filename=" + filename)
log_message(filename, "Test permission error")
```

Error is either a permission denied or the following (depending on whether file pre-exists or not):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Apps/Quotes/testLog.py", line 11, in <module>
    log_message(filename, "Test security")
  File "C:/Apps/Quotes/testLog.py", line 4, in log_message
    file1 = open(logFilename, "a")  # append mode
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Apps\\Quotes\\data\\GetQuoteslog__2020_08_11.txt'
```

Edit/Update:
I think I changed the path name to simplify a longer path name, and thus my code does not reproduce now, when I put in the correct directory name.  I think I assumed the double underscores was the problem.
But this was part of much larger program, which started getting that error when I added the date time to my log filename.  I might have jumped to conclusions, but unfortunately cannot reproduce at this time.
I don't think the double underscores was the problem at all.

Comment: Double underscores should not be used in strings in the way that you are using them. This is just a bad naming convention, and it won't work in python 3. As far as does it apply to a string in quotes. I would relate back to the line "if __name__ == __main__". To me, this would mean that double underscores would have a certain significance especially in quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have a problem opening files with double underscores. If you're getting a permissions error, it's because the file is already opened somewhere. If you don't have it opened in another program, then it's possible that it didn't get closed correctly. This might be due to running into an error before hitting "close". To avoid this in the future use:

```
def log_message(logFilename, logMessageText):
    with open(logFilename, "a") as file1:
        file1.write(logMessageText + "\n")
```

The other problem you're having with the FileNotFoundError is because, well, the file doesn't exist. If you want to create it if it doesn't exist, your 'mode' string should be `"a+"`, not just `"a"`. So the final function name should read:

```
def log_message(logFilename, logMessageText):
    with open(logFilename, "a+") as file1:
        file1.write(logMessageText + "\n")
```

EDIT:

That bring said, you should avoid using double underscores, as it's true that Python uses these to denote special variables and functions. Best to keep clear of them for clarity's sake, if possible.

Comment: Are you sure?  Read the meaning of "a" vs "a+" here.  See https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-read-write-file#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20add%20more,%22%20or%20%22a%2B%22%20mode.&text=Opening%20a%20file%20with%20%22w,%2C%20use%20%22a%2B%22%20mode.

Comment: I think I actually changed my directory name when simplyfing the code for testing and posting here, which was giving erroneous results when I posted. Right now, I cannot reproduce the error. Works fine with "a" and "a+".

Comment: Also, I do keep the log file open in NotePad++, and that has never been an issue.  NotePad++ detects is has changes and prompts me to re-open it.